# PHP: change parameters to pages

Tags: php, html, web, parameters

Hi everyone I Was Searching a lot about this but I couldn’t find anything and I want to know what is the name of this process and does it work

I want for example from this `example.com/home` to this `example.com?page=home`
I’ve given an example to it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXwaK.jpg)

Comment: This is called URL rewriting, it's usually done in the webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is called URL rewriting. When there is need to hide the actual URL then it helps. Check https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting
this for further details

Comment: Thank You Very Much But I want from example.com/home TO example.com?page=home